# Understanding customized has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through, has-many

Given association in User class:

```
has_many :followers, through: :follows_as_fallowable,
source: :user
```

It returns user instances that follow a given user. But when i started to dig deeper i realized that i don't completely understand why does this association(user.followers) returns User objects.
Based on what? I know that it can deduce by name of the association or class_name hash argument, but neither of these actually matters in this case.
I don't have Follower model and i have not provided class_name attribute.
Source parameter just say that it should search by user column in join table.
So how does Rails know that it should select from Users table?

EDIT:
follow_as_followable is another association in User model:

```
has_many :follows_as_fallowable, class_name: 'Follow', as: :followable
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails would be picking up knowledge of the User through the `follows_as_fallowable` relationship, using the association name specified by `:source`, which is `:user` (e.g. the `User` model).

While it's not show in the question, it's likely that the model containing `follows_as_fallowable` has a `belongs_to :user` relationship defined, hence the use of `source: :user` to specify which relationship through which to navigate.

You can see more information in [The has_many :through Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) section of the [Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) guide.

Comment: Well but follows_as_followable is another association(see edit) i don't understang where does it refer back to the user?